# Testing action with spock in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I have an action that I would like to test for when content-type is `application/json`

My action looks like this:

```
def save () {
  request.withFormat {
     json {
        def colorInstance = new Color(params.colors)
        render "${colorInstance.name}"
     }

     html {
       //do html stuff
     }
  }
```

I've got the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
def "js test" () {
    when:
    controller.save()
    request.contentType = "application/json"
    request.content = '{"colors": {"name": "red"} }'

    then:
    response.contentAsString == "red"
}
```

I believe the problem is in the way I'm sending json to the controller in my test. Is this the correct way?

Error is:

```
response.contentAsString == "red"
|        |               |
|        null            false
```

If I slightly modify the controller to be:

```
     json {
        def colorInstance = new Color(params.colors)
        render "${params.colors}"
     }
```

then also the error is same:

```
response.contentAsString == "red"
|        |               |
|        null            false
```

So I suspect that `params.colors` is never reached to the controller...?

Comment: js is for JavaScript, use 'json' inside withFormat to handle json.

Comment: I've changed that now but still same error. I think the json is not being passed to the controller.

Comment: You are calling the action before setting the `content-type` in request inside the test.

Comment: :( changed the order to be request.content-type request.content and then controller.save() but still same result. Getting back null. Its really the json data that is not being set.

Comment: Things work ok if I change request.content to controller.params.colors. But I wonder if that is the right way...

Comment: Exactly, [data binding](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/single.html#dataBinding) is with request parameters instead of the request body. If you want to access the `json` object in the `action`, it can be accessed as `request.JSON`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30177/discussion-between-anthony-and-dmahapatro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

Note:- I used `given` to set parameters. Looks like setting as `JSON` to request also binds to `params` in controller.

```
def save() {
        request.withFormat {
            json {
                def colorInstance = new Color(params.colors)
                render "${colorInstance.colorName}"
            }

            html {
                //do html stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

//Domain Color

```
class Color {
    String colorName
    Boolean isPrimaryColor
}
```

//Spock Test

```
def "json test" () {
        given:
            request.contentType = "application/json"
            request.JSON = '{colors: {colorName: "red", isPrimaryColor: true} }'
        when:
            controller.save()
        then:
            assert response.status == 200
            assert response.contentAsString == "red"
    }
```